# flutter_form_builder dropdown layout modification

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

How can I change the layout of flutter_form_builder DROPDOWN & get the result something like on an attached screenshot (labelText on the left side & values on right )? I found how to change in the library source code but this way looks wrong. I am new to the Flutter framework :). Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_form_builder` doesn't restrict the layout of your app. You can therefore just use your dropdown within a row widget and achieve something similar.

Kindly note that in your case you won't need to set the `labelText` within `InputDecorarion`.

```dart
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text('Cycle'),
        ),
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: FormBuilderDropdown(
                attribute: 'cycle',
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                hint: Text('Select Cycle'),
                items: ['7 Day', '14 Day', '21 Day']
                    .map((c) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: c,
                        child: Text('$c'),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
             ),
        ),
    ],
),
```

This is what I was able to achieve:

[image]

If this isn't exactly how you want it, flutter_form_builder has `FormBuilderCustomField` with which you can make your own custom fields.